# iPhone phone call detection software

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, phone-call

Has anyone any idea about how www.mrnumber.com works for iPhone? As far as I know, in iPhone, we can not detect an incoming phone call because the following code

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

will execute in case of launch of any other iPhone process. How do I get to know that this other process was an incoming phone call?

Answer (score 2):

It is not working on the iphone the same as on the android

All the iPhone version doe's is -

> **Status for calls and texts**
>   Mr. Number brings the idea of status from IM and chat to calls and texts. Let your friends on Mr. Number know when you’re free for a call, when you prefer text, and when you’re tied up. You can even tell Mr. Number to send all your calls to voicemail and let your friends know when you’re free again.
>
> **Reverse lookup**
>   Getting calls or texts from numbers that you don’t recognize? Mr. Number can return a name for over 70% of US phone numbers. Enter the number or copy and paste from your recent calls. Once you find out who it is, you can add them to your contacts with one click. And Mr. Number users have posted comments about tens of thousands of phone numbers used by telemarketers, debt collectors, robodialers, and other harassing callers so that you don’t waste your time.

When a call is coming your are dead, and there is nothing you can do about it.